# NextJs: Multiple children were passed to <Link> with the same `href` when I map

Tags: next.js, hyperlink

How do I easiest map through an array of menu items using the NextJs < Link > component?

The code I have is:

```
{navigation.map((item) => (
  <Link
    key={item.name}
    href={item.href}
    className={classNames(
      router.pathname == item.href
        ? 'bg-indigo-800 text-white'
        : 'text-indigo-100 hover:bg-indigo-600',
      'group flex items-center rounded-md px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium'
    )}
  >
    <item.icon
      className="mr-3 h-6 w-6 flex-shrink-0 text-indigo-300"
      aria-hidden="true"
    />
    {item.name}
  </Link>
))}
```

Which works using < a > tags instead of < Link >. The error message I get says:

"Error: Multiple children were passed to  with `href` of `/admin/home` but only one child is supported [https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-multiple-children"](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/link-multiple-children%22)

Now I could hard code the menu items, but that is not what I want to do.

The items themselves look like this:

```
const navigation = [
  { name: 'Dashboard', href: '/admin/home', icon: HomeIcon },
  { name: 'Users', href: '/admin/users', icon: UsersIcon },
  { name: 'Products', href: '/admin/products', icon: FolderIcon },
]
```

Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your problem is as the error says you are passing multiple children to the Link component

So if we breakdown your Link component that you are trying to map we can see the problem.

```
  <Link>
    <item.icon /> //ITEM 1 
    {item.name} //ITEM 2 
  </Link>
```

What you should have is a parent for the children you are trying to pass.

```
  <Link>
    <div> //This is now just 1 item
       <item.icon />  
       {item.name}  
    </div>
  </Link>
```

So your final code will end up looking like this

```
{navigation.map((item) => (
  <Link
    key={item.name}
    href={item.href}
    className={classNames(
      router.pathname == item.href
        ? 'bg-indigo-800 text-white'
        : 'text-indigo-100 hover:bg-indigo-600',
      'group flex items-center rounded-md px-2 py-2 text-base font-medium'
    )}
  >
   <div>
      <item.icon
        className="mr-3 h-6 w-6 flex-shrink-0 text-indigo-300"
        aria-hidden="true"
      />
      {item.name}
   </div>
  </Link>
))}
```